# Android convert relativelayout into image view:

Tags: android

Convert the current relative layout into ImageView in Android:

> Java coding in android:

```
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            L1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            L1.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bm = L1.getDrawingCache();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
           String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
  });
```

In Android current layout convert into imageview INTO  ENCODEDIMAGE.In layout image and textview .While viewing encoded image,imageview occurs correctly but there no textview.

Comment: From where image is coming to imageview?

Comment: bmImage.setImageBitmap(b);